# Adapting 楽しい時を過ごしてください

Tags: usage

Can you "adapt" the phrase 楽しい時を過ごしてください ("Have fun" or "Enjoy your time") to refer to a specific situation? I.e. if I want to say "enjoy your time in Hokkaido" or "enjoy your time with your friend [who is visiting]" or ...

If yes, how would I go about it?

- 北海道、楽しい時を過ごしてください。
- 北海道で、楽しい時を過ごしてください。
- something else?
- (ご)家族と、楽しい時を過ごしてください。
- something else?

If none of these work, do you have other suggestions for wishing people a nice time, but being a bit more specific about it? The level of politeness I need right now is somewhat formal (equivalent to a friend's parent) but I'd love to learn about any more casual options, too.

Comment: I think 楽しい一時【ひととき】 "some fun period" would be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel 楽しい時を過ごしてください is a bit hard. I think 楽しんできてください is more common than it.

For example, 北海道を(で)、楽しんできてください,　家族と楽しんできてください。

Casual options are 楽しんできて、楽しんできなよ.